# I want to delete a link of my wordpress site that is not accesible or visible anywhere on dashboard

Tags: wordpress, url, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am new to wordpress and don't know where to find specific things. I am creating a page that goes like example.com/audi but it always converts to example.com/audi-2. When I check the example.com/audi it opens a page of my site with posts layout but it is not editable with elementor or wordpress editor. This is happening with a few of the pages ( /audi, /porsche and /mercedes.etc ).

Now I did some R&D and found these links in the XML of the demo content of the theme I'm using. I think these posts are created from the demo content. But I cannot find a way to either delete these or change their URLs/posts so I can use my desired URL(they are required for SEO purpose). I've tried finding these in database and in the directory but I did not succeeded. I cannot export the demo content again with removing these links from the XML as I've done much customization on the website at the moment and don't want to start again from the start. Removed cache and all to see these anywhere in the dashboard but all in vain. Any guidance will be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have categories like this? You can change the link to the category in the settings.

Comment: Yes I've categories with these names, I tried deleting or renaming them but they don't have any effects on the pages at all. I also have other categories and created pages with those exact names and they're working fine. This rules out categories to have any conflict with this.